# Inconsistency in REST calls between folder and library creation

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

In the process of automatisation creation of a sub sites with a few libraries I have noticed some inconsistencies between how one would create a library and a folder using the REST API.

For creating a library (or list) you need to specify the Title of the library, this means you can use otherwise restricted characters since SharePoint strips them from the actual url. The path to the library with the Title "SharePoint / Onedrive" would simply be "SharePoint%20%20Onedrive".

Now when creating a folder you would specify the relative path to the new folder. Unlike when creating a library this throws an error if you use restricted characters (Like "/"). It does make sense why it throws an error since the path cannot contain a "/" - but is it possible to create a folder specifying the title seperately?

Answer (score -1):

A list/library has two "names". When first created, the name entered is used for both the library's URL and for the Name property. You can then change the Name property in the list/library settings page.

A folder is treated as a file and the "name" is the URL to the folder. You should get the same errors from REST when creating a new file or a new folder. You can add additional metadata columns to a folder: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2007/08/sharepoint-how-to-create-links-from.html

Folders have a Title column, but it is hidden (for editing) by default, and cannot be unhidden in the default Folder content type. You can inherit from Folder and then reveal the Title property. This new Content Type can be added to the library, and the Views modified to display the Title column, which can contain characters like "/".

Comment: Yes that I'm fully aware of. My point here is that how the two REST endpoints are working is inconsistently. One (The list/library endpoint) handles special characters perfectly fine. The other (creation of folders) does not handle it at all.

Comment: So this was not a question... but rather a complaint about the REST endpoint designs? You may want to submit the idea/bug here: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com

Comment: No it was a question on how to work around it as I would like the folder to display some of the special characters, but the url to leave them out. Exactly like the library does. I have long ago given up on complaining about anything Microsoft decides to do or not to do in regards to SharePoint.

Comment: (not the only one! ;-) )  Is using another folder Content Type an option? I created a FolderWithTitle content type that inherits from Folder and changed the Title property from Hidden to Optional. I could then manually add a new folder, and then edit it to change the Title to any text. I could not find a single REST command to create this new folder with additional metadata. I was able to update the Title property from REST. What I'm still looking for is how to create a folder from a custom folder content type.

Comment: Yeah seems like at it's base the two rest calls are fundimental different. Adding the hidden Title unfortunately only would solve the browers navigation, but not when synced to Onedrive or a network share :-( I guees the client will have to accept there are some limitations to what they can call a folder.